# ::after is not working in shadowroot (web component). I am trying to give some styling after div. Any workaround?

Tags: html, css, web-component, pseudocode, shadow-dom

`::after` is not working in shadowroot (web component). I am trying to give some styling after div. Any workaround? After  i am trying to give arrow. This  is coming under #shadow-root. For that i have written the following css:

But unfortunately it is not working in the web components. Please help!!

```
  #siteMapPanel .nav-appgroup.selected::after{
    position: absolute;
    color: #003e74;
    top: 100%;
    left: 45%;
    content: "\25B2";
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #003e74;    
    font-size: larger;
  }
```

I wanted to show a triangle arrow after

Comment: would you mind providing a minimal, reproducible example for the same?

Comment: add some more code here

Comment: You can insert executable stack snippets See: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: I also have this use case where `::part(foo)::before` is working in shadowDOM but not `::part(foo)::after`. Maybe because of the slot encapsulation ? Could not find an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

And here is an example of using a pseudo-element in web-components

```js
(function () {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = '<slot />';

  class test extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      const style = document.createElement('style');

      this.appendChild(style);
      this.attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      });

      style.textContent = `
        .text { 
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: arial;
          font-size: 50px;
          font-weight: 700;
          margin: auto;
        }
        .text::after {
          position: absolute;
          color: #003e74;
          top: 100%;
          left: 50%;
          content: "\\25B2";
          border-left: 20px solid transparent;
          border-right: 20px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 20px solid #003e74;    
          font-size: larger;
        }
      `;

    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
  customElements.define('test-example', test);
})();
```

```html
<test-example>
    <div class="text">PSEUDO-ELEMENTS</div>
  </test-example>
```